# How to drilldown multi-series spline charts multiple levels in HighCharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How can I drill down multi-series **spline chart** to other multi-series in HighCharts?

I've created bar charts without issue, however, spline is different because it has multiple values and I haven't been able to get drilldown to work.

I'm attempting to display a 6-month trend at a Territory level, which should drilldown to display 6-month trend for regions. Regions should drilldown to display 6-month trend for individual locations.

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: "spline"
        },
        title: {
            text: "6 Month Trend"
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: "Click the lines for more details."
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category",
            categories: [
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Territory",
            data: [
                1.5643,
                1.572727,
                1.5915,
                1.587355,
                1.575984,
                1.57
            ],
            drilldown: "regions"
        },
            {
                name: "Company",
                data: [
                    1.563662,
                    1.572306,
                    1.59114,
                    1.587355,
                    1.567452,
                    1.545366
                ]
            }
        ],
        drilldown: {
            allowPointDrilldown: false,
            series: [{
                id: "regions",
                data: [{
                    name: "Region 1",
                    data: [
                        1.5643,
                        1.57183,
                        1.59077,
                        1.584542,
                        1.570491,
                        1.566667
                    ],
                    drilldown: "region-1"
                },
                    {
                        name: "Region 2",
                        data: [
                            1.5643,
                            1.57183,
                            1.59077,
                            1.584542,
                            1.570491,
                            1.566667
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                id: "region-1",
                data: [{
                    name: "Location 1",
                    data: [
                        1.6643,
                        1.37183,
                        1.79077,
                        1.484542,
                        1.470491,
                        1.366667
                    ]
                },
                    {
                        name: "Location 2",
                        data: [
                            1.7643,
                            1.87183,
                            1.39077,
                            1.684542,
                            1.470491,
                            1.866667
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: "<span style=\"color:{point.color}\">●</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b><br/>"
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            labels: {
                format: "{value:.2f}"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/webaholik/buocz9gh/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts drilldown module works for points, not for series:

```
    series: [{
            name: "Territory",
            data: [{
                    y: 1.5643,
                    drilldown: true
                },
                {
                    y: 1.572727,
                    drilldown: true
                },
                ...
            ]
        }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tx5vjk7s/